# Adapter returning same item twice

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a ListView holding some items. It shows the result of a search in database, where two items meets the criteria of the select sentence.

When i do the search the first time, it returns twice the same item. But, when I click the search button again, this time it is done ok, showing both items. What could I do to get the items properly the first time?

Adapter:

```
public class ListaExpedientesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<BeanListaExpedientes> listaExpedientes;
private LayoutInflater inflater=null;
private Context c;

public ListaExpedientesAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<BeanListaExpedientes> lista){
    this.listaExpedientes=lista;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(c);
    this.c=c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listaExpedientes.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return listaExpedientes.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_exp_adapter_layout, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.numexp=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textnumexp);
        holder.nombrecomercial=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textnombrecomercial);
        holder.nombrecompleto=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textnombrecompleto);
        holder.foto=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.searchfoto);
        holder.codficha=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textviewcodficha);
        holder.numexp.setText(String.valueOf(listaExpedientes.get(position).getNumexp()));
        holder.nombrecompleto.setText(String.valueOf(listaExpedientes.get(position).getNombrecompleto()));
        holder.nombrecomercial.setText(String.valueOf(listaExpedientes.get(position).getNombrecomercial()));
        holder.foto.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listaExpedientes.get(position).getFoto()),dpToPx(80), dpToPx(80), true));
        holder.codficha.setText(String.valueOf(listaExpedientes.get(position).getCodficha()));
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(holder==null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();
    }



    return convertView;
}

private int dpToPx(int dp)
{
    float density = c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return Math.round((float)dp * density);
}
static class ViewHolder{
    TextView numexp;
    TextView nombrecompleto;
    TextView nombrecomercial;
    ImageView foto;
    TextView codficha;

}
}
```

The piece of code where the SQL sentence is launched (its inside a thread):

```
Cursor csr=db.rawQuery(sentencia, null);
listaExpedientes=new ArrayList<BeanListaExpedientes>();
        if(csr.moveToFirst()){

                 do {
                     codficha=csr.getLong(3);
                     codexpediente=csr.getLong(15);
                     nombrecompleto=csr.getString(8);
                     nombrecomercial=csr.getString(13);

                     Cursor csr2=db.rawQuery("select path from fotos where codficha="+codficha+" LIMIT 1", null);
                     if(csr2.moveToFirst()){

                          path=csr2.getString(0);

                                            }
listaExpedientes.add(new BeanListaExpedientes(path, nombrecomercial, nombrecompleto, codexpediente, codficha));
                      }while (csr.moveToNext());
                            refreshAdapter();
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those lines

```
 holder.numexp.setText(String.valueOf(listaExpedientes.get(position).getNumexp()));
 holder.nombrecompleto.setText(String.valueOf(listaExpedientes.get(position).getNombrecompleto()));
 holder.nombrecomercial.setText(String.valueOf(listaExpedientes.get(position).getNombrecomercial()));
 holder.foto.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listaExpedientes.get(position).getFoto()),dpToPx(80), dpToPx(80), true));
 holder.codficha.setText(String.valueOf(listaExpedientes.get(position).getCodficha()));
```

go outside the if/else logic. Your `getView` is called at least `getCount` times, but only once with `convertView = null`

Edit,

after you initalize the `holder`, when `convertView` is null, don't forget to call `convertView.setTag(holder)`

Comment: Alongside with fixing an error with holder being null the second time, and because of that the UI components being null (solved) your solution worked perfectly. Thank you! Will upvote when I can.

Comment: holder should always null when convertView is null. You have to call convertView.setTag(holder)

Answer (score 1):

Please remove in the first this line

```
if(holder==null){
        holder=new ViewHolder();
    }
```

and use the following line in getview

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

remove this line from `ListaExpedientesAdapter` constructor

```
inflater=LayoutInflater.from(c);
```